# how to capture touch event in lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, event

Is there any way to capture touch functionality in touch mobile screen.
currently i am using the onmousedown="{!c.onMouseDown} function to capture the mouse click events, but now for mobile screen i need to capture the touch event. 
when user touch the screen, it should capture the event.
I am using ontouchstart , but it is not working

```
<div class="slds " onmousedown="{!c.onMouseDown}" ontouchstart="{!c.onMouseDown}">
```

Controller

```
onMouseDown : function(component, event, helper){
        var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:notifEvent");
        appEvent.setParams({
            "isMouseClicked" : true });
        appEvent.fire();

    },
```

Comment: ontouchstart is the event for that can you share your full code

Comment: @User6670 I have added the controller code. for mouse click it is working, but touch it is not firing